# Unable to link shared object

Tags: c++, buildroot, ldd

I'm having issues linking my application to a shared object. I've cleanly built buildroot including packages host-thrift and host-openssl.

`ldd --verbose libthrift.so` yields the following:

```
./libthrift.so: /home/ano/workspace/source/open-source/buildroot/output/host/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ./libthrift.so)
./libthrift.so: /home/ano/workspace/source/open-source/buildroot/output/host/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ./libthrift.so)
./libthrift.so: /home/ano/workspace/source/open-source/buildroot/output/host/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ./libthrift.so)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffda06bc000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /home/ano/workspace/source/open-source/buildroot/output/host/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f0c37c10000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /home/ano/workspace/source/open-source/buildroot/output/host/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f0c377d9000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0c375bb000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0c3723f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0c36f39000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0c36b74000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0c3695d000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0c36759000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0c38129000)

    Version information:
    ./libthrift.so:
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3.1) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.9) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (OPENSSL_1.0.0) => not found
        libssl.so.1.0.0 (OPENSSL_1.0.1) => not found
        libssl.so.1.0.0 (OPENSSL_1.0.0) => not found
    /home/ano/workspace/source/open-source/buildroot/output/host/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /home/ano/workspace/source/open-source/buildroot/output/host/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0:
        libdl.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.7) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_4.2.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.18) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Which indicates that there's something fishy:

```
./libthrift.so: /home/ano/workspace/source/open-source/buildroot/output/host/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ./libthrift.so)
./libthrift.so: /home/ano/workspace/source/open-source/buildroot/output/host/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ./libthrift.so)
./libthrift.so: /home/ano/workspace/source/open-source/buildroot/output/host/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ./libthrift.so)
```

As far as I've been able to google, this can happen when you build against a newer version of a library than the one you're trying to run with. But this is not the case here (unless my host's libraries are playing me a trick I can't see).

Also:

```
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (OPENSSL_1.0.0) => not found
libssl.so.1.0.0 (OPENSSL_1.0.1) => not found
libssl.so.1.0.0 (OPENSSL_1.0.0) => not found
```

Yet these files are there in the same folder built at the same time.

**What I've tried:**

**1.**

Playing with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` does not affect the issue since `libthrift.so` is built with rpath:

```
readelf -a libthrift.so | grep PATH
0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/home/ano/workspace/source/open-source/buildroot/output/host/usr/lib]
```

**2.**

Checking file types:

```
> file libthrift.so
libthrift.so: symbolic link to `libthrift-0.9.2.so'

> file libthrift-0.9.2.so
libthrift-0.9.2.so: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=2dd133dea99a83cd5a8a9873e91503df3b7d7359, not stripped

> file libssl.so.1.0.0 
libssl.so.1.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=52c9028d053f16d05b6e1ff35605019182c8b28d, not stripped
```

**3. (new info)**

Copied my local `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0` and `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0` into `/home/ano/workspace/source/open-source/buildroot/output/host/usr/lib/`.

This *did* infact fix the problem, so now, if I understand it correctly, it seems like when libthrift.so was built in buildroot, it used my local `/lib` libraries instead of the ones that was built by buildroot itself.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be a bug in the `host-thrift` package in buildroot. `host-thrift` declared a dependency to `host-boost` but did not specify `--with-boost` and `--with-boost-libdir` config options for host build.

I set `HOST_THRIFT_CONF_OPTS` to:

```
HOST_THRIFT_CONF_OPTS = --with-sysroot=$(HOST_DIR) \
    --with-boost \
    --with-boost-libdir=$(HOST_DIR)/usr/lib \
    --disable-tests \
    --disable-tutorial
```

and that fixed the problem.

Comment: So, what happened is that you had the Boost libraries installed on your host machine, so Buildroot picked up those ones rather than the one it had built in $(HOST_DIR) ? If so, your change seems correct, can you submit a patch to the Buildroot mailing list ? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's what happened. I'll try to submit a patch.